# Defining properties (docstrings) for Emacs key bindings

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, keymaps

I [currently] don't use the menu feature for want of screen real estate, so it's possible the answer lies there.

Is there any way to associate a docstring with a keybinding such that it'll show up in the `C-c C-h` (or related) help displays?  Right now all I get is either `Prefix Command` or the name of the function/lambda to which the key is bound.  I'd *like* to have something about the purpose of the prefixed keymap for the former, and explanatory text for the more obscure functions for the latter.

Yes, I know that clicking on the function name will bring up a help window with details; I'm just looking for a one-liner property that can be shown in the original `*Help*` pane without disrupting the screen layout with new panes.

I suspect the answer is 'no,' but it seems a fairly obvious feature..

Thanks!

Comment: I think the answer is if you want it, you need to implement it.  The function that ultimately makes `C-h b` and related buffers is `describe-buffer-bindings`, which is unfortunately written in C.  Something somewhat close to what you want is `apropos-command` and other `apropos-` commands.

Comment: Also, take a look at the helpful package: https://github.com/Wilfred/helpful

Comment: Would be a nice feature, and does seem like a fairly obvious one to have. If you use `define-prefix-command` it takes an optional documentation argument that will display in the minibuffer, but not show up in the *help* buffer as far as I'm aware. @jpkotta I looked at that package as well, but it didn't look like it implemented this feature